# Open in ConEmu right click menu windows 7

Tags: windows, conemu

How to put ConEmu in context menu in windows 7, when click on folder to be able to choose Open in ConEmu?

Comment: As a software developer -- I find many of the questions that are closed as "off-topic" to be very useful and very much on-topic.  I think that some moderators on SO are too eager to show that they are being useful, or that they have power, and close many questions that should remain open.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Configure it like this:

*Settings* → *Integration* (or *Settings* → *Features* → *Integration* in older versions)

Set up the *ConEmu Here* group (don't misuse *ConEmu Inside*) and press the *Register* button.

[image: ConEmu Screen Shot]

These options are stored in the registry (Explorer related keys) and that's why these settings are not stored the ConEmu configuration, so the *Save settings* button is useless on that particular page.

Comment: Its working, but I get some error: Cant find appropriate parent window! ConEmu icon in context menu fails too...

Comment: I looked at the file and see that everything's back to the old settings, how to save your settings permanent? I used save settings button only

Comment: Very old build on the screenshot. Update strongly recommended.

Comment: @user3310809, don't misuse "ConEmu Inside" instead of "ConEmu here". Different mode, behavior, requirements.

Comment: how do you get the icon in conemu (not the right click explorer menu) to change to what you want it to be?

Comment: "ConEmu here" doesn't seem to work if you have set a default startup directory. Does anyone know how to make them work together?